# How to access JSON object that starts with a # in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am connecting to an API that serves data in JSON format.

I currently have a variable that is supposed to store the URL of an image pulled from the API, it looks like this:

```
var getImageURL = ALBUM_DATA.results.albummatches.album[x].image[0].#text;
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Property '#text' does not exist on type 'any'
```

Comment: Is the variable actually named with a hash symbol? That seems wrong on a few levels. if you `console.log(ALBUM_DATA.results.albummatches.album[x].image[0])` what does that show?

Comment: Hi John, when I use that command this is returned: `{size: "small", #text: "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/4cfc22122b6a4885aff6bc7ce903b9a0.png"}`